# Merging custom and default options in Symfony form AbstractType defined in setOptionDefaults()

Tags: php, symfony

### Structure

I have a base controller (`ContentEditControllerBase`) that does all the standard functionality for editing a page. This base controller is extended by the controllers of many different edit pages, often simply passing in some basic options to the base controller. The base controller loads a form that edits a View object via a custom formType based on the type of page that is loaded (each edit page form looks different).

**Edit the Article Itself (unique bundle for unique content type)**

```
Route: /Admin/Article/Edit
Controller: \Gutensite\ArticleBundle\Controller\ArticleEditController (extends ContentEditControllerBase)
FormType: \Gutensite\ArticleBundle\Form\Type\ArticleEditType (extends ViewType)
```

**Edit the SEO Fields for this page (standard CMS editing fields for all pages)**

```
Route: /Admin/Content/SEO/Edit
Controller: \Gutensite\CmsBundle\Controller\ContentSeoEditController (extends ContentEditControllerBase)
FormType: \Gutensite\CmsBundle\Form\Type\ContentSeoEditType (extends ViewType)
```

The ViewType form that is extended loads a custom `ViewVersionType` form (some options need to get passed to this associated entity inside that form).

**ContentEditControllerBase *(extended by all editing pages)***

```
// the View Object is created
$view = new View;

// We determine the correct custom formType to load based on settings for the 
// particular editing page being loaded (e.g. some pages will edit the main 
// content, others the SEO settings. This will create a path like:
// \Gutensite\CmsBundle\Form\Type\ContentSeoEditType
$formTypePath = $currentPage->getBundleInfo()['bundleNamespace']
                    .'\Form\Type\\'.$$currentPage->getBundleInfo()['controller']
                    .'Type';

// We then load the correct formType and pass in any options, e.g. access level to different fields (i.e. will this form show the publish button or just the save button)
$form = $this->createForm(new $formTypePath, $view, $options);
```

### Setting Options

Inside the ViewType we use `setDefaultOptions()`, with some sensible default values (see code below). This allows my controller to pass in options to the custom form type. And my `ViewType` form passes on some of those values to the `ViewVersionType`.

However, I need to be able to set default values, and then overwrite only specific values, so in effect these options need to **MERGE**. Currently, if I pass in custom options, the entire array of default values is overwritten.

### The Classes Code

**ContentSeoEditType *(Extends the ViewType with extra fields)***

```
namespace Gutensite\CmsBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ContentSeoEditType extends ViewType
{

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'contentSeoEditType';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        // Enable existing options on ViewVersion object
        $options['options']['viewVersion']['enableGroup']['seo'] = TRUE;

        /**
         * Add New Inputs to View object
         */
        $builder->add('routing', 'collection', array(
            'label' => false,
            'type' => new RoutingType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype'     => true,
            'by_reference' => false
        ));

        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    }


}
```

**ViewType *(the form type that includes associated forms)***

```
namespace Gutensite\CmsBundle\Form\Type;

use Gutensite\CmsBundle\Entity\View;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ViewType extends AbstractType
{

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'view';
    }


    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Gutensite\CmsBundle\Entity\View\View',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            // Custom Options
            'options' => array(
                // Options for viewVersion
                'viewVersion'       => array(),
                // Enabling Options
                'enableAction' => array(
                    'create'        => TRUE,
                    'save'          => TRUE,
                    'publish'       => FALSE,
                    'version'       => FALSE,
                    'duplicate'     => FALSE,
                    'delete'        => FALSE
                )
            )
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        // Pass Specific Variables to ViewVersion Options (when loaded below)
        $options['options']['viewVersion']['enableAction']['publish'] = $options['options']['enableAction']['publish'];


        $builder
            ->add('version', new ViewVersionType(), array(
                'label' => false,
                'required' => false,
                // Pass options to viewVersion form type
                'options' => $options['options']['viewVersion']
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

**ViewVersionType *(Custom Form Type base)***

```
namespace Gutensite\CmsBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ViewVersionType extends AbstractType
{

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'viewVersion';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Gutensite\CmsBundle\Entity\View\ViewVersion',
            // Add a custom option bucket
            'options' => array(
                    'enableField'       => array(
                        'title'         => FALSE,
                        'versionNotes'  => FALSE,
                        'timeCustom'    => FALSE
                ),
                'enableAction'      => array(
                    'publish'       => FALSE
                ),
                'enableEntity'      => array(
                        'viewSettings'  => FALSE,
                        'content'       => FALSE
                ),
                'enableGroup'       => array(
                        'layout'        => FALSE,
                        'seo'           => FALSE
                )
            )
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // **********************************
        // ERROR: $options['options'] does NOT have all the default options listed in setDefaultOptions()
        // Only has $options['options']['enableGroup']['seo'] = 1
        // Only has $options['options']['enableAction']['publish'] = 1
        // **********************************


    }
}
```

### SUMMARY OF THE PROBLEM

How can I set default options on the formType, and also allow my controller to pass in specific custom options to overwrite only that option, i.e. merge my custom options with the default options. I need to be able to pass options from ViewType to sub form ViewTypeVersion that is loaded from ViewType as well (same merging).

Comment: Merging nested arrays is not currently supported but discussion are underway: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4833

Answer (score 4):

Default options are not made to merge. That's the expected behavior. They are called default because they only exist if you did not define them. You can read more about the interface [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html)

Here is the part of the code that overrides your options in OptionResolver:

```
// Make sure this method can be called multiple times
$combinedOptions = clone $this->defaultOptions;

// Override options set by the user
foreach ($options as $option => $value) {
    $combinedOptions->set($option, $value);
}
```

There is no need to define your arrays under "options" use your own unique indexes.

```
// These options will be available for you
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'enableAction' => array('publish' => FALSE),
    'enableEntity' => array(
        'viewSettings'  => FALSE,
        'content'       => FALSE
     ),
));
```

Another flexible way of creating forms and making them share options is by [creating them as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service). That way you can share the options in the config as you wish.

Finally, extending FormType is not the same as extending classes. Symfony can not resolve options and dependency when you extend classes as you did for ContentSeo form type. FormType inherit from each other by defining the `getParent()` method in the class. Using the `getParent()` method in one class let symfony knows that this form inherit from the other and the options will be resolved correctly.

**Your main problem here is two issues:**

- First, you are trying to use `options` which is used my symfony already and if you dig into the code you will see that symfony checks to see if it defined or not before trying to merge anything. You should be using your own index keys and not one that symfony uses by default.
- Second, You need to use getParent when extending a form type rather than extending the class.

Try with these two changes and see how it works for you. I believe that should be a good start.

Hope that helps clear some questions.

Comment: 1. If I don't define my values in an `options` array, how can I pass them into `$form = $this->createForm(new ViewType, $view, $myOptions);`? The options I pass there, end up as $options['options'] in my formType. I need to be able to pass options from my controller to the custom formType.

Comment: 2. I read about the OptionsResolver component. Can this be used in any object? It seems very powerful, but still there is no method for merging options? How is that not a common requirement for others? I need to set default values so that my formType can check if they exist without giving errors, but I need to be able to overwrite the defaults (from the controller or a parent formType) on a case by case basis. How "should" I do that?

Comment: You can always consider passing your options in the ViewType `__construct($options) { $this->options = $options; }`. `$form = $this->createForm(new ViewType($myOptions), $view);`

Comment: OptionsResolver is the one used by forms in symfony btw. that's where setDefaults() come from. You have access to all the interface there.

Comment: I still can't understand why it's so difficult to merge custom options with default options. I must be structuring something incorrectly if no one else has this problem, i.e. there must be a better way to set default options for the formType and pass in custom options (from controller or other parent form types) to overwrite specific defaults without changing others. What is that better method?

Comment: I can easily custom code something, but I want to do it the "Symfony" recommended way. If I pass in options into the construct as you suggested, they aren't related to the resolvers default options. So I'm bypassing the built in formType methods and the existing options parameter which seems like it was created for passing options into form types...

Comment: Also, per your statement "They are called default because they only exist if you did not define them." This is the behavior I want. So I think the problem is that I am defining my defaults in an array (to keep them sanely grouped), the `optionsResolver#setDefaults()` doesn't do an `array_replace_recursive()` it just does a loop on the values and overwrites them at the top level... So... I could write my own custom setDefaults() that did a recursive merge. Is that a bad idea? Should I change it and submit a pull request?

Comment: FYI, Evidently there has been discussion about this problem on gitbhub for over a year: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4833

Comment: I updated the two main code issues that I believe is non standard and can be the main reason behind the issues you are having.

Comment: My `ViewType` extends AbstractType, and has the standard fields for View. The reason I then create ContentSeoEditType extends ViewType is so that my controller can load the formType that is the same name as the controller (to do this dynamically), AND so that I can add more fields if I need to. So I am using this like a normal PHP extend. It works well, but you are saying this confuses symfony somehow? I tried to make it do what you say but when I make it extend AbstractType instead of ViewType and getParent returns ViewType, it gives error "Could not load type 'ViewType'".

Comment: I don't understand how to use anything other than 'options', since that is the only value that I can pass in from the controller when I load the form type. Can you show me some code to illustrate what you are referring to?

Comment: Even if I change options to 'myOptions', and make them one level (not an array), it still doesn't merge them...

Comment: `$form = $this->createForm(new ViewType(), $view, array('customOption' => $somethingImportant));`

Comment: getParent() should return the same that the parent form is returning in getName() .. so if viewType is returning `viewform` in getName() .. then to create a child form you need getParent() to return `viewform`. Check how symfony form types are created to get an idea how the symfony way works

Comment: For some examples https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Form/Type

Comment: in setDefaults() add `customOptions => null` and it will be considered a known option and will allow you to add it.

Comment: when I use the `ContentSeoEditType extends AbstractType` along with `getParent() { return 'view'; }`, I do not get all the code defined in `ViewType#buildForm()` which is the entire reason why I wanted to extend `ViewType` (because all my content editing pages are editing different aspects of the View and ViewVersion entities, so we just reuse the same code).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62852/discussion-between-chadwick-meyer-and-ramy).

Answer (score 1):

¿Why don't you overwrite `buildView` function in your custom *FormTypes*?

The `$view` variable, has a property called `vars` which contains the *options* (once resolved), whose you may need to update with an actually merged value.

Take a look a this example:

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    //some code ...

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['options'] = array_merge($this->fixedOptions,$view->vars['options']);
    }

}
```

```

Answer (score 0):

Support for nested options was added in [this PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/27291).  The [official Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html#nested-options) also describes the feature well.  The basic idea is that Symfony needs to know if a specific option supports nesting, then it will allow it.

As an example usage for custom Form Types:

```php
class CustomType extends AbstractType {

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
      'option1' => true,
      'option2' => function (OptionsResolver $resolver) {  // Nesting enabled!
          $resolver->setDefaults([
            'create' => true,
            'maxItems' => 5,
          ]);
        },
    ]);
  }
```

Then from your controller or another Type:

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void {
  $builder
    ->add('custom', CustomType::class, [
          'option2' => [
            'create' => false,
            // 'maxItems' will default to 5!
          ]
      ]);
}
```